# Data Manipulation within data frames

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have solar power consumption data from AUSGRID(Australian utility -publicly shared data) . As you can see this is time series data of solar power consumption for different customer classes for different dates across 2010 . In order to analyze this time series data of solar power consumption, i am trying to manipulate data in Python data frame  to get data in the desired format for analysis. I am struggling to get the desired output format and would welcome all help on this
[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s14cK.jpg)

I have attached the expected format.
[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwQQX.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Picture are very poor medium to exchange data, copy paste and format instead. Also read [ask] and [mcve] for more details.